# Sort a list based on a given distribution

Tags: python, sorting

Answering one [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281624/977038), I ended up with a problem that I believe was a circumlocution way of solving which could have been done in a better way, but I was clueless

There are two list

```
percent = [0.23, 0.27, 0.4, 0.1]
optimal_partition = [3, 2, 2, 1]
```

optimal_partition, is one of the integer partition of the number 8 into 4 parts

I would like to sort `optimal_partition`, in a manner which matches the percentage distribution to as closest as possible which would mean, the individual partition should match the percent magnitude as closest as possible

So `3 -> 0.4`, `2 -> 0.27` and `0.23` and `1 -> 0.1`

So the final result should be

```
[2, 2, 3, 1]
```

The way I ended up solving this was

```
>>> percent = [0.23, 0.27, 0.4, 0.1]
>>> optimal_partition = [3, 2, 2, 1]
>>> optimal_partition_percent = zip(sorted(optimal_partition),
                    sorted(enumerate(percent),
                       key = itemgetter(1)))
>>> optimal_partition = [e for e, _ in sorted(optimal_partition_percent,
                          key = lambda e: e[1][0])]
>>> optimal_partition
[2, 2, 3, 1]
```

Can you suggest an easier way to solve this?

By easier I mean, without the need to implement multiple sorting, and storing and later rearranging based on index.

Couple of more examples:

```
percent = [0.25, 0.25, 0.4, 0.1]
optimal_partition = [3, 2, 2, 1]
result = [2, 2, 3, 1]

percent = [0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2]
optimal_partition = [3, 2, 2, 1]
result = [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: define "easier way to solve this"

Comment: @Woot4Moo: A single sort based on key instead of multiple sorts and storing and retrieving indexed as was done in my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from numpy import take,argsort

take(opt,argsort(argsort(perc)[::-1]))
```

*or without imports:*

```
zip(*sorted(zip(sorted(range(len(perc)), key=perc.__getitem__)[::-1],opt)))[1]
```

---

```
#Test

l=[([0.23, 0.27, 0.4, 0.1],[3, 2, 2, 1]),
   ([0.25, 0.25, 0.4, 0.1],[3, 2, 2, 1]),
   ([0.2,  0.2,  0.4, 0.2],[3, 2, 2, 1])]

def f1(perc,opt):
    return take(opt,argsort(argsort(perc)[::-1]))

def f2(perc,opt):
    return zip(*sorted(zip(sorted(range(len(perc)),
             key=perc.__getitem__)[::-1],opt)))[1]       

for i in l:
    perc, opt = i
    print f1(perc,opt), f2(perc,opt)

# output:
# [2 2 3 1] (2, 2, 3, 1)
# [2 2 3 1] (2, 2, 3, 1)
# [1 2 3 2] (1, 2, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Hah, much simpler than my approach.

Comment: Looks interesting. I will have to experiment a bit with this before I can come back with a response

Comment: Unfortunately in both the zip and the `numpy` case, the third example seems to be a bit off track. `3` should actually map with the highest pct distribution which is `0.4`. I think your `numpy` solution is elegant and pretty close, but there is something obvious which both of us is missing. I will work a bit with your `numpy` solution before looking beyond.

Comment: @Abhijit: I initially misunderstood the objective, I have now corrected my answer.

Comment: Its now way too perfect. Thanks a lot for your effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that the percentages sum to 1:

```
percent = [0.23, 0.27, 0.4, 0.1]
optimal_partition = [3, 2, 2, 1]
total = sum(optimal_partition)
output = [total*i for i in percent]
```

Now you need to figure out a way to redistribute the fractional components somehow. Thinking out loud:

```
from operator import itemgetter
intermediate = [(i[0], int(i[1]), i[1] - int(i[1])) for i in enumerate(output)]
# Sort the list by the fractional component
s = sorted(intermediate, key=itemgetter(2))
# Now, distribute the first item's fractional component to the rest, starting at the top:
for i, tup in enumerate(s):
    fraction = tup[2]
    # Go through the remaining items in reverse order
    for index in range(len(s)-1, i, -1):
        this_fraction = s[index][2]
        if fraction + this_fraction >= 1:
            # increment this item by 1, clear the fraction, carry the remainder
            new_fraction = fraction + this_fraction -1
            s[index][1] = s[index][1] + 1
            s[index][2] = 0
            fraction = new_fraction
        else:
            #just add the fraction to this element, clear the original element
            s[index][2] = s[index][2] + fraction
```

Now, I'm not sure I'd say that's "easier". I haven't tested it, and I'm sure I got the logic wrong in that last section. In fact, I'm attempting assignment to tuples, so I know there's at least one error. But it's a different approach.